# Custom number class to be used as out parameter

Tags: java

There is no "out" or "ref" parameter in Java (I maybe wrong because I haven't touched Java in 3 yrs.). I am thinking create classes, like MyInteger, MyFloat and MyDouble, to be used as out parameter. is there a way to combine them into ONE generic class?

Sample code for MyInteger class:

```
public class MyInteger
{
   private int value = 0;

   public int getValue(){ return value;}
   public void setValue(int newValue) {value = newValue;}

}
```

**EDIT:**

how to use MyInteger class:

```
public boolean aMethod(int input, MyInteger output)
{
   boolean status = true;
   //calculation here;
   //set status to false if anything wrong;
   //if nothing wrong do this: output.setValue(newValue);
   return status;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

What I am asking is I hope I can combine MyInteger, MyFloat, ... into ONE generic class.

Comment: Are you asking about calling a stored proc via jdbc with in-out parameters?

Comment: Are you recreating the wrapper classes like http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html?

Comment: I still don't understand why you need this functionality. What do you mean by out/ref exactly?

Comment: pass in a reference parameter and assign a new value to it, when that method exit, the new value is available to the calling method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the fact that out parameters are somewhat awkward and I would not recommend them, why don't you use `Integer` and the like?

Since they all extend  `Number` you could do:

```
public class MyNumber<T extends Number>
{
 private T value = null;

 ...
}
```

Comment: there is no way to assign a new value to Integer instance, I think. as a out parameter, it should be able to carry a new value out the called method.

Comment: Yes, that's why I proposed `MyNumber<T extends Number>` which then can be a `MyNumber<Integer>`, for example. With this you could call `myNumber.setValue(1);` or - without autoboxing - `myNumber.setValue( new Integer(1) );`

Answer (score 4):

You can use AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, AtomicReference etc. They do exactly what you are suggesting, and as an added feature they are highly thread-safe

---

And in response to this comment:

> but why there is no AtomicFloat and
>   AtomicDouble

Here's what [the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) say:

> Additionally, classes are provided
>   only for those types that are commonly
>   useful in intended applications. For
>   example, there is no atomic class for
>   representing `byte`. In those infrequent
>   cases where you would like to do so,
>   you can use an `AtomicInteger` to hold
>   byte values, and cast appropriately.
>   You can also hold floats using
>   `Float.floatToIntBits` and
>   `Float.intBitstoFloat` conversions, and
>   doubles using `Double.doubleToLongBits`
>   and `Double.longBitsToDouble`
>   conversions.

My own take: That sounds awfully complicated, I'd go with `AtomicReference<Double>`, `AtomicReference<Float>` etc. instead

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  OP's "MyInteger" class does what he wants in the case (inside aMethod, call output.setValue(whatever)), but there's no need to reinvent a holder class when Atomic* exists.

Comment: but why there is no AtomicFloat and AtomicDouble?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, if you are using Objects / Visitor patterns properly, you should never need to return more than one value from a method.

Return an object which contains more than one value

```
public Pair<Integer, Double> method3();
```

or use a visitor to recieve more than one value.  Useful if you can many out comes/errors.

```
public interface Visitor {
    public void onValues(int i, double d);
    public void onOtherValues(double d, String message);
}

method(Visitor visitor);
```

or you can update the object method is called on, rather than return the values.

```
public void method() {
    this.i = 10;
    this.d = 100.0;
}
```

e.g.

```
Worker worker = new Worker();
worker.method();
int i = worker.i;
double d = worker.d;
```

or you can return an valid value on a condition.

```
// returns the number of bytes read or -1 on the end of the file.
public int read(byte[] bytes);

// index of the search key, if it is contained in the array within the specified range; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1)
public int binarySearch(Object[] array, Object key);
```

---

There is a generic holder you can use [AtomicReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html)

```
public void method(AtomicReference<Integer> i, AtomicReference<Double> i);
```

For some types there is a built in type AtomicBoolean, AtomicInteger, AtomicLong

```
public void method(AtomicBoolean flag, AtomicInteger len);
// OR
public boolean method(AtomicInteger len);
```

You can also use a plain array

```
int[] i = { 0 };
double[] d = { 0.0 };
method2(i, d);

public void method2(int[] i, double[] d);
```

Comment: Great answer, contains every possible solution I can think of (+1)

Comment: return ONE value only but not from the method return, i expect it is return by the parameter. for example, I want the method return true or false after some calculation and I also need the result number from the calculation which will be carried out by a parameter

Comment: @Joachim, Thank you for fixing the typos.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA, you might find you can overload a return value. e.g. merge the boolean and number into one like read() or binarySearch().  However, I suspect setting two fields of an object is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your new classes subclass Number.  The only reason Integer, Float, etc. are immutable is because that's how they're implemented.

Alternately, you could create a NumberHolder class that you pass around, that has a mutable Number field.

```
class NumberHolder {

  private Number num;

  public void setNumber(Number num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  public void getNumber() {
    return num'
  }

}
```

Comment: You could make this generic so you can change it.

Comment: but i cannot see how can i use it as the Integer, Float and Double?